# how you design prototypes in erlang?

Tags: erlang, prototyping

in the early phase of design of erlang small app - how do you do prototyping?

Is it better to first prototype without OTP just to prove all main mechanics in plain erlang and in further elaboration add what OTP offers with refined requirements / aspects or use OTP from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The answer below is not trying to plug my instructional, it just happens to apply directly to the OP's question; were it possible I would just send the OP a private message or email. At the time of this answer my demonstration system is only *barely* worth even reading, aside from basic architecture concepts.)

I start with a slew of function stubs. I do this in most languages (even something like this in assembler). The special thing about this in Erlang is that my initial stubs represent supervisors or logical managers, not one-off solutions to elements of my fundamental problem.

Beyond that, I like to do something most people abhor these days: talking the problem out in prose to discover inconsistencies in the way I view the problem. I've *just* started on an example of this here (as in, I'm still working on this before and after work daily as of today, 2014.11.06): http://zxq9.com/erlmud.

Some system stubs (conceptual, not OTP -- which is integral to the idea I'm trying to demonstrate in the project, actually) are here: https://github.com/zxq9/erlmud/tree/be7c6a8ae0d91aac37850083091ae4d15f1369a4/erlmud-0.1 for example. Over the next few days they will change significantly until there is a prototype system that works instead of just stubs. If you're *really* curious about this, follow the commits from the one I linked over the next two weeks or so (paid work schedule permitting, of course).

One positive thing I've noticed about prototyping with stubs and not jumping straight into OTP behaviors is that very often the behavior that is assumed to be a proper fit for a component turns out not to be. There are many cases where I anticipate I will want a gen_server, but after writing some stubs and messing around a bit I find myself beginning to manually implement an FSM. Sometimes that happens in reverse, too, I think I need an FSM and wind up writing a server, or realize I could benefit from a proper gen_event. Once you've ironed out what you're doing it is pretty easy to convert pure Erlang into OTP. It is much less easy to edit your mental model of how a component works once you've written a gen_fsm or gen_server, because you start to feel invested in the idea of thinking of it in OTP terms prematurely.

Remember: typing is the *easy* part, the real battle is figuring out what to type. So begin boldly by writing executable stubs and toy with them.

Comment: very nice! this is something I had in mind - thanks alot for inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

There is no special recipe to do prototypes in Erlang. How would you do a prototype in Java, C#, Scala, (put any language here) ?
When prototyping, you need to achieve your proof of concept as fast as possible and deliver a minimal vital project.

In your case, does `OTP` helps you to deliver your minimal vital project or not?
If yes, then use it. And of course don't use it if it isn't.

Are you familiar with OTP concepts in the first place? If not, then you need to learn them. And thats mean that you need to invest more time in learning OTP. Is that ok for your prototyping purpose?
I'm only trying to highlight the fact that prototyping in Erlang isn't different from any other language.

Comment: Erlang is unique in several aspects in comparison with other general purpose languages so is the design of the applications.

Comment: @user3169252 You can classify any language as unique when it tries to approach a problem.